Gradle does not permit writing to files in build directory
I am working on a gradle plugin that downloads a file with tiny mappings to remap a spigot plugin that remaps nms into other mappings, either obfuscate them back from mojang or remap into an intermediary format so another plugin can remap the plugin into the current obfuscated "mappings" while running on a server to allow from cross-version NMS usage

URL url = new URL(String.format(MAPPINGS_URL, MINECRAFT_VERSION));

        File mappingFile = new File(

                "build" + File.separator + "mappings",

                "mappings-" + MINECRAFT_VERSION + "-intermediary.tiny"

        );



        if(!mappingFile.exists()) {

            mappingFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

            mappingFile.createNewFile();



            try (InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();

                 OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(mappingFile.toPath())) {



                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                return;

            }

        }


This is my code, it should download the mappings file into a directory in the build folder. When the plugin tries to download the mapping file, it throws this exception:
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: build\mappings\mappings-1.19.4-intermediary.tiny

The line it is thrown on is the line the OutputStream to the mappings file is opened.
I have tried running the code as a standalone application, on a pre-compiled jar which was not remapped and when decompiling was in mojang mappings, and it worked without a single issue.

I'm not sure why your answer was deleted by a mod (their comment doesn't really seem to apply) . That said, I cannot reproduce your issue with a dummy binary plugin (implemented via either buildSrc or using includeBuild(...)) using Gradle 8.7 on Windows 11.

As an aside, you can use Files#copy(InputStream,Path,CopyOption...) to simplify the implementation. Or if you're targeting Java 9+ and you don't want to use the java.nio.file API: InputStream#transferTo(OutputStream).
